# youtube-dl in a crontab displays "[Errno 13] Permission denied"

Tags: permissions, scripts, cron, youtube-dl

I am on Debian. I try to make a cron job for youtube-dl. It consists of a daily script, starting at midnight. 
When I execute the script manually, everything is working perfectly. However, when I use the cron job, I have got an error like this :

```
ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/Video/...
```

The cron is the following :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
@daily /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl-script.sh >> /var/mail/nextcloud 2>&1
```

I understand, there is a permission issue somewhere, but I don't know how to solve it.

For your information :

- owner/group of the target folder (`/media/Video/`) is : `www-data` (owner), `wwww-data`
  (group)
- owner/group of the script is : `nextcloud` (owner), `root`
  (group)
- `nextcloud` and `root` belong to the group `www-data`
- and the target folder (`/media/Video/`) permission is `770` (owner/group group can read/write/execute, others can't do anything).

Please, could you help me ? I have seen a similar topic but the solution was not successful as the problem was not exactly the same. Thank you very much.

**EDIT (old status) :** so far, I have tried to copy my script (`youtube-dl-script.sh`) in `/etc/crontab.daily` folder, by respecting the rules (removing the `.sh` extension and script owned by `root` / group `root`). And checking with `cat /etc/crontab` gives me this output :

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

So, normally, it should have worked at 6:25 AM this morning, but it didn't !

I have discovered that other scripts have `-x`as a final bit, therefore, I have made `chmod +x youtube-dl-script`.

- Before that, the script is `-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 1682 juin  16 02:24 /etc/cron.daily/youtube-dl-script`.
- Now, it is `-rwxr-x--x 1 root root 1682 juin  16 02:24 /etc/cron.daily/youtube-dl-script`.

I have now to wait until tomorrow 6:25 AM to see if this works.

**EDIT 2 (current status) :**  so it doesn't work. I have even made `chmod 755` in order to have the same persmissions as all other scripts, and I have reboot the server, but it does not work.

What is very strange is that if I do `run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily`, my script is listed so it should be runned by `cron.daily`

Please, if you have any idea, feel free to inform me. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you download to /home/user/media instead? Please also note cron doesn't inherit any environment variables

Comment: The owner/group of the *script* don't really matter here - it's the owner/group of the cron *process*. Whose crontab are you placing this in?

Comment: @steeldriver : the crontab is stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`. 
@colbycdev : no because the folder is in an external drive (so it is in /media folder mandatory). 
Thank you both, please feel free to help me !

Comment: @prog-amateur how are you setting up crontab? From crontab - e on your user? Also can you access the folder from command line yourself?

Comment: @colbycdev : thank you. Yes, I have used both `crontab -e` and sudo `crontab -e` (because I was testing). And from nextcloud user, or root user, I can access to /media/Video without issue.

Comment: @prog-amateur have you tried placing a script in /etc/cron.daily? It would achieve the same effect

Comment: @colbycdev thank you very much, I didn't know about `/etc/cron.daily`(to be honest, I have started to learn cron 3 days ago ! so I am a very beginner). I will pu the script there, but, how can I test it ? How I will know it works or not, shall I wait for tomorrow midnight ?

Comment: @prog-amateur should run daily just like your old script. How were you testing it before?

Comment: Note that if you choose to place your script in `/etc/cron.daily`, its name must conform to the rules described in `man run-parts` (in particular, it cannot have a `.sh` or any other "dot extension") and it must be owned by `root`. See the `DEBIAN_SPECIFIC` section of `man cron`

Comment: @colbycdev : on the crontab, you need to replace `@daily` by the time you want it to be executed. For instance it is 3:00 AM so to test it at 03:01, you need to repace `@daily`by `1 3 * * *`

Comment: @prog-amateur not entirely sure if cron.daily override that or not, never tested

Comment: @steeldriver : thank you very much for the tip ! I will remove the `.sh`extension. Please, if the file group is `root`but the owner is `nextcloud` do you think the script will be executed ?  (For your information, owner/group of the script is now `root/root`)

Comment: Please always add new or otherwise relevant information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: @dessert sorry, this is just because we havn't found the solution yet. I will try to edit the 1st post when the information will be relevant for the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK, I have found the solution :**

First, I have moved the script to `/etc/cron.hourly`, because there were no `anacron` installed, and because I would like to use it every hour. But it didn't worked.

Then I have run `sudo service cron status`just to check if cron service was active. It was, but I have also found an interresting warning, something like `your token was expired, renew your token`. So I have searched for this error message on Internet and have found that my root password needed to be renewed, otherwise cron would not work correctly. To check this, I had to use `sudo chage -l root` which showed that my root password was `expired`.

Therefore, I have renewed my root password with `sudo passwd root` and I have checked again with `sudo chage -l root` which showed that the password is now OK. Now, everything is running fine, and cron is working as expected !